# Node-Djikstra on NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I am a newbie programmer . I had experience building a restful API using NodeJS and I want to implement Djikstra algorithm in my API to route and stuff

```
const Graph = require('node-dijkstra')

const route = new Graph()

route.addNode('A', { B:1 })
route.addNode('B', { A:1, C:2, D: 4 })
route.addNode('C', { B:2, D:1 })
route.addNode('D', { C:1, B:4 })

route.path('A', 'D') // => [ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' ]
```

I am trying to run those code but I got error

```
TypeError: route.addNode is not a function
```

But I tried to run at https://npm.runkit.com/node-dijkstra and it is working.

I dont know if I do any mistake or anything that prevent the code to run properly because I have lack knowledge about this stuff

Comment: Could you include an example of how you're trying to run the code? Is it a standalone file or as part of a webapp?

Comment: @jdrd im sorry , i dont get what are you trying to say. I put all the code in a file named test.js and i tried to run it with command "node test.js"